# Linux command/script to find all files in a directory with a 4 digit number <= a specific number

Tags: linux, bash, script

I have a folder containing several other folders, each named in this format:

```
Company XYZ (1999 OneWordDescription)
```

I'm trying to filter out the ones that are marked 1995 or older, so I can move them to another folder, and then manually delete them. The date modified/created won't help, as these have all been modified since, and the created dates just aren't accurate for some reason.

What Linux command or script could I run to move everything with "(1995" and older to a different directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move all folders for years from 1980 to 1995, inclusive, run:

```
shopt -s nullglob
mv *'('{1980..1995}*/ /some/path/
```

The `shopt -s nullglob` command is not strictly necessary but it eliminates error messages if any of the years are missing.

The above uses brace expansions, `{1980..1995}` to generate all the years explicitly.  You can see how brace expansion works using just an `echo` statement:

```
$ echo {1980..1995}
1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995
```

Comment: Will this recurse through directories, tho? That's what stumped me to the point where I was about to break out perl

Comment: @Jarmund `mv` will move whole directories, contents and all.  Is there a `Company XYZ (1999 OneWordDescription)` directory somewhere below the current directory that you want to find?   If so, we can use `extglob` or `find`.

Comment: Thanks, this works! There are no subdirectories that need to be located.